# Why won't my long polling $.ajax request get a new JSON feed (when refreshing the page does)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have set up long-polling with ajax to monitor an ever-increasing JSON feed.  The only issue is that, while my code does get called and it seems the requestes are being made (I am monitoring the console, to see the console log but I also see on the network panel of Chrome's developer tools that I am indeed making success requests.  However my counter, the `globalLength` (which is essentially just the length of the JSON feed) does not update after I first one open the page.

Once or twice I have noticed that if I directly go to the JSON feed page, the page doing the long-polling will get the new image urls.

Also, refreshing the page doing the long-polling usually gets the new JSON feed items.  It is quite strange.  I attached my code, the only part I haven't used before is the `$.deferred` element.

Thanks

```
var streamUrl = 'json feed url';
var idCheck = [];
var def = $.Deferred();
var globalLength = 0;


//Long polling that waits for create array function to finish before getting called again
$(function(){
    (function poll(){
        var def = $.Deferred();
        console.log('about to get');
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log('getting');
            $.ajax({
                url: streamUrl,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                     createArray(data, def);
                },
                complete: function () {
                    $.when(def).done(function () {
                        console.log('all loaded');
                        poll();
                    });
                }
            });
        }, 7000);
    })();
});


function createArray(data, defer) {
    console.log('creating array');
    var entries = data.entries;
    var urlArray = [];
    for (var k = 0, j = entries.length; k < j; k++) {
        var id = entries[k]['id'];
        if (idCheck.indexOf(id) == -1) {
            idCheck.push(id);
            urlArray.push(id.url)
        }
        if (urlArray.length) {
            preLoadPictures(urlArray, defer.resolve);
        } else {
            defer.resolve();
        }
    }
}

var preLoadPictures = function(pictureArray, callback){
    var loaded = 0;
    for (var i = 0, j = pictureArray.length; i < j; i++){
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function(){
            checkLoad();
            console.log('load');
        };
        img.onerror = function(){
            img.src = badURL;
            checkLoad();
            console.log('bad image source error');
        };
        img.src = pictureURLs[i];
    }
    function checkLoad(){
        loaded++;
        if(loaded == pictureURLs.length && callback){
            console.log('The length is ' + globalLength);
            callback();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: really not clear what isn't working

Comment: should be declaring a new `$.Deferred` every time, not a global one

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear @charlietfl - no new images are being downloaded (I updated my answer).

I also tried making `$.Deferred` local, (see code) but nothing changed.

Comment: @Startec Have you tried watching the XHR tab of your developer tools? Are the requests actually going out every 7s? Is the correct response coming back?

Comment: Yes, the are going out every 7 seconds and coming back with a `200` response each time...

Comment: Further testing shows that the feed is indeed updating. I think that fixing the `$.Deferred` was most important.  Also what I realized is that there is more of a delay than I thought.  While getting the JSON url after an image was updated immediately showed the new length, sometimes it took a couple of ajax calls (even with the 7 second `timeOut`) is this common behavior or a bug with the feed I am using?

Comment: sounds more like feed isn't updated as quickly or often as you expect

Comment: Yes - it just seemed that opening the feed in a new browser was immediate whereas doing an `$.ajax` sometimes took a few requests. Haven't used ajax that much I didn't know if this was normal.